# How do I calculate the no of days, from input type checkboxes (I have weekdays as checkboxes)

Tags: c#, jquery

I have two input fields - date 1 and date2 I calculated the difference between two dates using jquery. let say it is 29 Now I have to check if a checkbox of Monday is checked true then out of 29 days, there will be 4 mondays then that would be my answer i.e. my result would be 4. Similarly, If have monday tuesday wednesday selected then I have to calculate that out of 29 there will be how many occurences of m,t,w and hence how much would be my result

```
// assume here days are 23, 29 or whatever
var days = PageUtils.GetDaysBetweenDates(start, end);

   //adding code for days calculation
        var selected = [];
        $('#weekDaysOptions input:checked').each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
        });
        // get the count of weekdays selected.
        var daysoFWeekare = selected.length;
// value of selected will be = 1, if out of 7 weekdays one is checked true, if 2 are checked then selected will be 2 and so on.
```

Comment: Not to be nit picky but you deleted your explanation for what you want...

Comment: done, added a code block

Comment: The idea of this site is to have a well formatted question with context so future users can quickly and easily find answers

Comment: agree, will add that

Answer (score 0):

You cant just use the difference in days because you have to know what day you started on. If you use the difference to loop and add days to start then record each day youll get a 7 index array with the number of occurences of each day.

Something like this should work:

```js
start = new Date(2017,9,14)
end = new Date(2017,9,24)
var days = (end - start)/(1000*60*60*24)// 10 days just for example, you already have this number
var daysOfWeek = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]// array to hold results 

for(var i = 0; i < days;i++){
 x = start.getDay();
 daysOfWeek[x] += 1;
 start = addDays(start,1);
}
console.log(daysOfWeek)



function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```